# KeyError exception with pandas dataframe colunm

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, error-handling

Imaging the one wants to make a function that accepts two kinds of DataFrames - with column "Value" and without. (Say, this is data on assets from different sources and some sources provide no information about value.)

Function `foo` should run different procedures depending on the dataframe, say, copy `"Value"` to new column "B" or add new column "B" with `1`. A toy example is as follows.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":["one", "two", "three"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A":["one", "two", "three"], "Value":[1, 2, 3]})
```

What is the best way to handle `KeyError: 'Value'` in the case of `df1`.

```
def foo(df, col_name="Value"):

    <if col_name exists>
        df["B"] = df[col_name] 
    <else>
        df["B"] = 1
    return df
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df['B'] = df.get('Value', 1)
```

or equivalently

```
df['B'] = df['Value'] if 'Value' in df else 1
```

Comment: thank you. Is there any reason to resort to some `try-except` structures in such cases (say, if situation is more complicated)?

Comment: @garej `try-except` is an excellent tool to catch exception (duh, it's born to do so). It certainly works in this case, even in the more general settings, *if you know what you're doing*. However, I learned that in R&D, it often provides minimal additional value, while making bug catching unnecessarily difficult. That said, I was advised by many system engineers to use them in productions so as end-users don't get awkward errors. **TLDR**: Sure, it works here, but I prefer the commands in the answer :D.